# HTML text input only allow alpha, numeric, and special characters like the password input does?

Tags: html, ios, forms

On a password input, it doesn't allow emoji characters. And on iOS you can't even choose to use a different keyboard when focused on a password input field. I'd like my normal text input to do the same.

I was thinking you could specify 'accepts-charset' on the input but you can not.

This is to prevent users from inputting emoji chars into a text field.

I know there are JS solutions for this but I was hoping there would be an attribute or something I could use to control it instead.

Also I tried setting the 'accepts-charset' on the form tag to "UTF-8" and a few other. It made no difference. :/

Comment: What is this “it” that does not allow emoji characters? And what is it that you actually want?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela "it" refers to the password input `<input type="password" ... >`. In mobile safari, when you focus on a password input, the keyboard that comes up does not have a button that allows you to switch to the emoji keyboard. When you focus on a text input ( `<input type="text" ... >` or a textarea, the button comes back up that will allow you to switch to the emoji keyboard. I want to not allow a user to enter in emoji characters in a specific textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking exactly for the same option, but didn't find the perfect solution.

Workaround is using type=number (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp). I just tried it on iOS and it works, but it defaults the Keyboard at the "123" Numeric-Special keyboard view, rather than the "ABC" Alphabet keyboard view.

But it indeed removes the Emoji keyboard!

Edit:
So this would work: `<input type=number>`.